# Indexing and Searching an "array" within an embedded document in MongoDB using Java

Tags: mongodb-java

Could any one, please tell me how to do -

Indexing and Searching  an "array" type within an embedded document in MongoDB using ***Java***.

For example: The outer document id UserDetails and the array is given below

```
"languages_known" : 
          [ 
             "English", 
             "Kannada",
             "Hindi",
             "German" 
          ]
```

I referred this : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-type-multikey.
But still I could not do.

Please tell to do Indexing and Searching for the above in ***Java***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build an index on array inside a document using below in mongo shell:-

```
db.collection_name.ensureIndex({languages_known: 1}) // In your case
```

In java driver you can use:-

```
collection.createIndex(DBObject keys);
```

Can you please clarify what did you try and errors that you may have encountered?

Comment: I could able to do this using below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630599/index-basic-array-type-in-mongodb-using-java

Comment: Could you please give a solution to the problem. The link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690620/node-discovery-disabled-in-elastic-search