# Searching a value in a specific field in MongoDB Full Text Search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-java

(MongoDB Full Text Search)

Hello,
I have put some fields in index and this is how I could search for a ***search_keyword***.

```
BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject("$search", "search_keyword"); 
BasicDBObject textSearch = new BasicDBObject("$text", search);

DBCursor cursor = users.find(textSearch);
```

I don't want ***search_keyword***  to be searched in all the fields specified in the index. *Is there any method to specify ***search_keyword*** to be searched in specific fields from the index??*

If so, please give me some idea how to do it in ***Java***.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if that can be done at all. Maybe for that purpose you need a full fledged search engine. I tried elasticsearch and it worked ok with the river plugin for mongodb.

Comment: @user3805045 how did you create your $text index?

Comment: For e.g. :                                                             BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject();                                    index.put("companyName", "text");                                      collection.ensureIndex( index, "TextIndex");

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to index a single field and search for it then it is the way it works by default. Lets say you want to index the field `companyName`. When you perform `$text` search on this collection, only the data from the `companyName` field will be used because you only included that field in your index.

Now the second scenario, your `$text` index includes more than one field. In this case you cannot limit the search to only look for values indexed from a specific field. The `$text` index is constructed on the collection level and a collection can have at most one `$text` index. Your option to limit search on specific field in this case may be to use `regex` instead.

MongoDB has the flexibility to fulfil requirements of other scenarios, but you can also evaluate using other technologies if your application is heavily search-driven and you are primarily after a full-text search engine for locating documents by keyword with a rich query syntax. [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) might be an alternative here. It really depends on the type of the application and your needs.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It's truly a very useful information.